# Override Controller in Multiple Custom Modules in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How to override same magento core controller in two different custom modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you may know you can easy override core controllers using the following xml (in config.xml file):

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <core_module>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <YouPackage_YourModule before="Mage_CoreModule">YouPackage_YourModule_YourController</YouPackage_YourModule>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </core_module>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

You can override core controller as many time as you want but you must be sure that actions in this controllers are different. If you want to override the same action you must resolve conflicts using some combined action. There is no way to call the same action from different controllers.

Comment: Hi azakolyukin, Thanks a lot for Quick response . As i have overrided a core controller in moduleA and now that same controller i was trying to override in moduleB also in both the modules i have taken the different actions but magento only calling actions which i have written in moduleA not of moduleB. so how can i overcome this problem so that i can use actions of both the modules (actions written in overrided controller in both modules). Thanks

Comment: In module B you should write `<YouPackage_YourModuleB before="YouPackage_YourModuleA">YouPackage_YourModule_YourController</YouPackage_YourModule>`.

Comment: the answer is incomplete, it works only if your second module/override (B) introduce a new method otherwise the first module/overried (A) will be initialized. see @Zyava answer for fixing this kind of issues ( also your second module need to extend the first one in this scenario )